# how can i change a Uri via button in a SelectionChanged method in c# for windows 8 application?

Tags: c#, button, windows-8, webview, selectionchanged

I develop a game guide application with c# for windows 8. I'm trying to put 2 youtube videos in a specific chapter of the game and I want to change the Uri of the Webview via a button. when the button is not pressed the first video uri is to be shown and when the button **IS** pressed the second video is to be shown. how can I do that? for example:

```
    private void Chapters_SelectionChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {           
        switch (Chapters.SelectedIndex)
        { 
            case 0:

                Chapter2C.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Chapter2T.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                next_but.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                prev_but.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                Mywebview.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                if (next_button.Clicked)
                 {
                    Mywebview.Source = new Uri("http://www.youtube.com/embed/F65paVQ0wn8?feature=player_detailpage") 
                 }
                   else 
                 {
                    Mywebview.Source = new Uri ("http://www.youtube.com/embed/rLdrc7K5vdw");
                 }
                 break;
        }
   }
```

anyone??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use toggle button.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnChangeChapter" Content="Change Chapter" Click="btnChangeChapter_Click_1"/>

private void btnChangeChapter_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /* TODO: use property btnChangeChapter.IsChecked.Value in SelectionChanged event,
            it's bool value */
}
```

If you want to use `ToggleButton` as app bar button style then check [this](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/03/19/creating-a-metro-style-toggle-button-for-appbar.aspx) out.